# Prove that If λ is an eigenvalue of A, then m(λ) = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

Prove that If $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, then $m(λ) = 0$.

I've been advised to use the fact that $m(A) = m_0 I + m_1 A + \dots + m_rA_r$, and use that $(A^i)x = (λ^i)x$.

How would I go about proving this?

Comment: It is unclear to me what the facts you are advised to use actually mean (and I would say that $m[A]=0$ by definition of $m$). On the other hand this is one of those occasions where "on the eigenspace of $A$ for $\lambda$, a polynomial $P[A]$ of $A$ acts by the scalar $P[\lambda]$" immediately does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then

$$ m(A)v = (A^n + m_{n-1}A^{n-1} + \dots + m_0 I)v = \lambda^n v + m_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}v + \dots + m_0 v = m(\lambda)v. $$

Thus, we see that $m(\lambda)v = 0$ and since $v \neq 0$, we must have $m(\lambda) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $m(A)=0_{n \times n}$. Then if $x$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector,
\begin{align}
0 &= m(A)x\\
&= m_0 x + m_1 Ax + \cdots + m_r A^r x\\
&= (m_0 + m_1 \lambda + \cdots + m_r \lambda^r) x\\
&= m(\lambda) x.
\end{align}